# Best way to combine two dicts, merging on values of first and keys of second

Tags: python

I have two dicts:

```
a = {"foo":["bar","baz"]}
b = {"bar":[1,2],"baz":[9,10]}
```

I want to merge them so that each element in the value of a (`"bar"` and `"baz"`) is replaced by the values in b, for which `"bar"` and `"baz"` are keys.

Desired output:

```
{'foo': [[1, 2], [9, 10]]}
```

This is how I'm currently implementing the merge:

```
for i,el in enumerate(a["foo"]):
    a["foo"][i] = b[el]

print a 
# {'foo': [[1, 2], [9, 10]]}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Also: Not sure if this is appropriate to ask in the same post, but I'd also like to learn a way to do this with pyspark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a list comprehension:

```
a['foo'] = [b[el] for el in a['foo']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and efficient Martijn Pieters...

We have a Beginner, so I will draw attention to mutable collections.

If a list in `b` is modified in the code bellow, `a` will be modified too.

```
a = {"foo": ["bar", "baz"]}
b = {"bar": [1, 2], "baz": [9, 10]}

a['foo'] = [b[el] for el in a['foo']]

expected = {'foo': [[1, 2], [9, 10]]}
assert a == expected
```

Example:

```
b["bar"][0] = 789
print(a)
assert a == expected  # AssertionError
```

You get:

```
{'foo': [[789, 2], [9, 10]]}
```

To avoid this, one can duplicate the lists with `list()` constructor or `[:]` syntax:

```
a['foo'] = [list(b[el]) for el in a['foo']]
# or: a['foo'] = [b[el][:] for el in a['foo']]

expected = {'foo': [[1, 2], [9, 10]]}
assert a == expected

b["bar"][0] = 789
print(a)
assert a == expected  # OK
```

If your are really paranoid, you can use [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy

a['foo'] = [copy.deepcopy(b[el]) for el in a['foo']]

expected = {'foo': [[1, 2], [9, 10]]}
assert a == expected

b["bar"][0] = 789
print(a)
assert a == expected  # OK
```